# how running a program elevated

Tags: windows-10, administrator, uac, privileges, elevated

I have two computers, say `A` and `B`, both running **`Windows 10 , build 1709`**,and having :

- current User only in Local group "users"
- with Local Administrator Account : enabled
- UAC : Enabled
- Printer Sharing : Enabled

I have tried my best to kept both computers identical as much as I can.
I want to run a program on both machines locally (no remote execution) with administrator rights and elevated.

#### On Computer `A`

Programs are running with elevated privileges, NO UAC message.

#### On Computer `B`

It shows some kinds of errors and UAC messages, for which I tried,

- Running program with `psexec`

  ```
  psexec.exe -i -u administrator -p "password" -accepteula path\program.exe
  ```

  That exits out showing error :

  ```
  ERROR : "this operation need an elevation"
  (original message : "L'opération demandée nécessite une élévation.")
  ```
- Running program with `Runas`

  ```
  runas /noprofile /user:administrator path\program.exe
  ```

  That exits out showing error :

  ```
  ERROR : "740 : this operation need an elevation"
  (original message : "740 : L’opération demandée nécessite une élévation.")
  ```
- Using `cmd.exe` to launch program

  ```
  psexec.exe -i -u administrator -p "password" -accepteula cmd.exe /C start "xxxx" path\program.exe
  ```

  **In this case, program is running as Administrator but privileges are still not elevated.**
- Now In the Running program,

  - I have to give it admin rights (elevated privileges) using compatibility tab.
  - After which program finally runs with elevated privileges but I got an UAC message.
  - So, I disabled UAC for Administrator account and Now, It runs with elevated privileges and no UAC message.

This problem is not specific to this program only, rather other applications ( such as  Bitdefender, Anti-Ransomware, Fraps, Paint-Shop pro 6 ) are also showing it.

And None of this happens on Computer A.

Also, `psexec` options like -h or -s has never worked for me, neither on computer A. It shows an error on starting service. So on computer B, I have to :

1. Launch it with cmd.exe
2. Use compatibility,
3. Disable UAC for administrator

I don't want to use compatibility and want to maintain UAC enabled, What I need to do to make computer B act like computer A. Basically doesn't show these UAC errors ?

So what could be the exact root cause and the solution for it ?

Comment: AS i write, i'm only a normal user (belonging only in users local group), I'm not the built-in Administrator, i'm not an administrator user or either a power user. I disabled UAC messages in control panel, users account, UAC settings.

Comment: secpol.msc settings are differents on A and B. Making all default everywhere and rebooting. I will tell.

Comment: There are a lot of UAC settings in secpol.msc. And i don't understand all of them. How is there differences on computer A and B from the default settings ? i don't know beause it's personnal computers and i never use mmc. So finaly the key was to restore default values in secpol.msc/local strategies/security options. Psexec and runas are working. Make an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Psexec and runas didn't work properly because of UAC settings.
I used secpol.msc to see what default settings have been altered and restore them.
UAC settings are in local strategies / security options.